# Moving cursor in react slate-editor

Tags: reactjs, react-slate

I'm trying to move the cursor in react slate-editor.

I tried to do it in 2 ways.

First:

```
// This code saving key in offset in variables
const nativeSelection = this.getSelectedText();
const nativeRange = nativeSelection.getRangeAt(0);
    const range = findRange(nativeRange, this.editor);
const offset = nativeRange.endOffset;
const key = range.anchor.key;

// OnChange is triggered by running the next line and cursor moves back
this.editor.blur();

// Trying to move to the cursor
this.editor.moveTo(key, offset);
```

Second:

```
const nativeSelection = this.getSelectedText();
const nativeRange = nativeSelection.getRangeAt(0);
const range = findRange(nativeRange, this.editor);
const clonedRange = _.cloneDeep(range);

// OnChange is triggered by running the next line and cursor moves back
this.editor.blur();

// Trying to move the cursor
this.editor.select(clonedRange);
```

Unfortunately, `select` and `moveTo` doesn't seem to affect the cursor position.
Can someone assist ?

Answer (score 7):

Try using `Transform.select` method combining with a [location](https://docs.slatejs.org/api/locations) point

Put cursor after 3rd letter

```js
Transforms.select(editor, {path: [0, 0], offset: 3});
```

Move to the very end

```js
Transforms.select(editor, Editor.end(editor, []));
```

You also can try the method `Transforms.move`.
Move cursor after 5th word:

```js
Transforms.move(editor, {distance: 5, unit: 'word'});
```

Or end the line:

```js
Transforms.move(editor, {distance: 1, unit: 'line'});
```

It is also worth noting that in my case I had to run the transformation in a setTimeout after setting the editor value. Example:

```js
setValue(content);
setTimeout(() => {
   Transforms.move(editor, {distance: 1, unit: 'line'});
}, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or more explicitly:

```
const lastNode = editor.children[editor.children.length - 1];
const lastNodePath = ReactEditor.findPath(editor, lastNode);
const endPoint = Editor.end(editor, lastNodePath);

Transforms.select(editor, endPoint);
```

Answer (score -2):

If you're using the latest version of Slate.js you can use Transforms.move(editor, { options })